# Video Background/ Chrome browser only shows video when user clicks on screen?

Tags: events, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, html5-video

I am using a video background plugin on this site http://kimcolemanprojects.com/index.html

Its works great on all browsers, only on chrome the video doesn't show until the user clicks on the screen, which is just a white screen.

Looks like its bound to a click event but I can not work out where. I can see no events bound to this page.

Thanks for your help.

Angela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange one indeed. It only happens for me when I open your site in a background tab. There are definitely no click handlers. (See "Event Listener Breakpoints" in dev tools.) And the video element does exist and is loaded, even though it's not displaying. So I suspect it's either a bug in Chrome or a quirk in how it handles certain slow-loading pages.

One thing that seems to make it show up is to tweak the CSS in the developer tools. So try adding this to your page at the end of the body element:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.display = '';
    }, 500);
  });
</script>
```

That works for me when I run it in the console, so hopefully it will work in script.

Also, there are a few easy things you can do to make the page load much faster and mitigate this particular problem, even if you can't make it go away completely.

1. Set a dark background color. That way, when the video takes some time to load, people will be able to see the white text immediately.
2. Make the video MUCH smaller. It's about 21MB, which is way too big for a background. It's encoded at around 3400kb per second, which is more than you need even for HD video on the web. Try it at 1000kb or even less. Maybe 500kb. And don't include an audio track in the video file.
3. Save the poster image as a jpg instead of png. It's 140kb. You can get it much smaller.
4. Put all your scripts (except for the mobile redirect) at the bottom of the body tag. This way you can at least get the text and background color displaying without having to load your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding the script does seem to help. It certainly doesn't seem to wait for an event now even if there is a slight delay. I will now work on reducing size of video and see if that helps further. Thanks again.